# Which you have ever seen

Tags: word-choice, which-that

So there's an article about the Cybertruck that starts out like this: "*The Cybertruck is already here and it doesn't look like any pickup truck **that** you've ever seen.*"

My (Russian native) friend says that you can replace 'that' with 'which' and it's gonna mean the same thing. But this doesn't sound good to me, I feel like it breaks the sentence somehow

I did my research, I was trying to find whether it's possible to do or not but I'm pretty much stuck. Can you actually do that? If so, what rule allows it? Thank you

Comment: It doesn’t strike me as ungrammatical, but _that_ does seem the more idiomatic option. Even more idiomatic would be to leave out the subordinator altogether and just say “like any pickup truck you’ve ever seen”.

Comment: My best guess is that '**which you've ever seen**' implies that I saw some weird-looking trucks in my life. Which can be false. Is there any way to identify this sentence to get more information about it?

Comment: It doesn’t imply that, no. It doesn’t imply anything different from the version with _that_ or no subordinator – if anything, all three imply that you **haven’t** seen weird trucks before (if you had, the Cybertruck would be less likely to be unlike any truck you’d ever seen).

Comment: In fact, we can do away with both 'that' and 'which' and just say, "The Cybertruck is already here and it doesn't look like any pickup truck you've ever seen."

Answer (score -1):

I genuinely appreciate the fact that your intuition professes this to be ungrammatical.

Grammarly has a really good, in-depth article on when to use which at https://www.grammarly.com/blog/which-vs-that/.

Replacing *that* with *which* in this sentence renders the sentence nonsensical. If you have to use *which* in the sentence nonetheless, use this sentence:

> "The Cybertruck is already here and it doesn't look like any pickup truck [on] **which** you could ever set your eyes on."

Comment: This does not actually answer the question.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Read again.

Comment: Your addition does at least address the question directly, but _which_ does not in any way render the sentence ungrammatical; that is just wrong. Your suggested rephrasing is no different with regards to _that_ vs _which_ (except if you choose to front the preposition, in which case _that_ is not possible): if _which_ made the original nonsensical, it equally makes your version nonsensical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I completely disagree. Have you noticed that I've changed the tenses? The use of 'which' is completely grammatical.

Comment: Also, the grammarly article is overly simplistic. _Which_ can introduce both defining and defining clauses, and _that_ can (occasionally, though much less commonly) introduce non-defining clauses  – the difference between the two is decided by context/semantics, pause and intonation. It’s a good rule of thumb to use _that_ for defining and _which_ for non-defining, but it is far from the whole truth and it does not describe actual English usage very well.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well then in this 'context', the given sentence makes sense.

Comment: The change of tense from present perfect to simple past does not make any difference whatsoever to the function of the subordinator here. I agree that the use _which_ is completely grammatical, but that is also the case for the original sentence given.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You mean to say that 'which' can be used with the tense in the question?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Though in both versions, _that_ or nothing at all would be more common. (Again, unless you start with “on which…”, in which case _that_ is not possible at all.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Could you make a sentence with 'which'? I'm piqued.

Comment: You mean just any sentence with _which_ introducing a restrictive/defining clause? That’s something which I can do very easily (case in point). More parallel cases to the one here (in perfect constructions) are also easy to find; [here’s one](https://bit.ly/2FH0giT) example. StoneyB wrote [an excellent BlogOverflow post](https://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/tw-a-pragmatic-approach/) about this some years back as well.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Okay, thanks.

Comment: Avoid saying *“the **below** X”* because this can sound stilted and even
borderline unnatural to native speakers. Instead say *“the **following** 
X”* in especially formal written contexts, or merely *“**this** X”* in many
common and less exacting circumstances. Sometimes English-language learners
don’t realize that they should use the demonstrative determiners *this,
that, these, those* which native speakers customarily use for these cases.